# getting an exception input string is not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

//  While adding the data into the list i am getting an exception that input string is not in a correct format.I am trying to store all the data of the first column starting from row 3 to end to a list.

```
public static int Get_Retail_Team_Id(string Incident_Path, Int32 Retail_Id)
{
    int lastRow = 0;
    List<Int32> List_Id = new List<Int32>();
    Excel.Application MyApp;
    Excel.Workbook MyBook;
    Excel.Worksheet MySheet;
    Excel.Range range;
    MyApp = new Excel.Application();
    MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(Incident_Path);
    MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets["team"]; // Explict cast is not required here
    lastRow = MySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell).Row;

    for(int i=3; i<=lastRow; i++)
    {
        if(MySheet.Cells[i,1].Value !="")
        {
            int val = Convert.ToInt32(MySheet.Cells[i, 1].Value);//Here getting an exception that input string is not in a correct format
            List_Id.Add(val);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    int Result=0;
    foreach (Int32 id in List_Id)
    {
        if(Retail_Id==id)
        {
            Result=1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Result=0;
        }
    }
    return Result;
}
```

Comment: What is the excel value format in ?

Comment: Whatever value is in `MySheet.Cells[i, 1].Value` cannot be converted to an `int`. Step through your code and find out why.

Comment: Ok thank you for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to parse the string ,if its a a valid int format as follows

```
int j;
if (Int32.TryParse(MySheet.Cells[i, 1].Value, out j))
    List_Id.Add(j);
else
    Console.WriteLine("String could not be parsed." + MySheet.Cells[i, 1].Value);
```